# How do I make a function that will get the window handle from my current process on Windows?

Tags: windows, rust

I'm using a scripting language for which I created a library in Rust, and I need a function that can return a window handle that belongs to the window of my program. My operating system is Windows and I will be calling this function from the dll I created for the game. The scripting language I use on the operating system contains only the show game window function, which displays the window, but the function returns only true or false. This scripting language is created in angelscrypt and was made to create games for blind users.

I tried to use the `windows_win` crate but when I compared the handle to the `getactivewindow` function from WinAPI so the results were different. here is
the code that i created but returned HWND from my function didn't match getactivewindow from winapi and result from get window text is DIEmWin.

```rust
pub fn find_window() -> HWND {
    let current_process_id = unsafe { processthreadsapi::GetCurrentProcessId() };
    let mut found_window: HWND = null_mut();
    loop {
        found_window = unsafe {
            winuser::FindWindowExA(null_mut(), found_window, null_mut(), null_mut())
        };
        let process_id:* mut DWORD = null_mut();
        unsafe {
            winuser::GetWindowThreadProcessId(found_window, process_id)
        };
        if unsafe { *process_id } == current_process_id {
            return found_window
        };
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn find_game_window() -> HWND {
    return utils::find_window();
}
```

Comment: "this code doesn't work well": Can you share any error messages you're getting?

Comment: Please [edit] all details into the question itself. Example outputs would also help clarify what is amiss.

Comment: Why don't you store the window handle after the window was created? Thread-local storage is probably the right place for it. A solution based on `FindWindow` is always flawed. It breaks the moment your program has two windows.

Comment: Handle storing is not possible because the scripting language I use does not allow it and therefore I need to get the handle in another way.
I can also tell you for sure that this scripting language can only create one window.

Comment: I'm hesitant to believe that there is **any** scripting language that wouldn't allow storing a 32-bit value.

Comment: Yes there is and it's name is bgt Blastbay game toolkit.